# What's the usage for convolutional layer that output is the same as the input applied with MaxPool

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

what's the idea behind when using the following convolutional layers?

especially for `nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding = 1)`

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, padding = 1 )        
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding = 1)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, padding = 1)
self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
```

```
 x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
 x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
 x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
```

I thought Conv2d always uses a bigger size like
from (16,32) to (32,64) for example.

Is `nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding = 1)` merely for reducing the size?

Answer (score 0):

The model architecture all depends on finally what works best for your application, and it's always going to vary.

You are right in saying that usually, you want to make your tensors deeper (in the dimension of your channels) in order to extract richer features, but there is no hard and fast rule about that. Having said that, sometimes you don't want to make your tensors too big, since more the number of channels more the number of trainable parameters making it difficult for your model to train. This again brings me back to the very first line I said - "It all depends".

And as for the line:

```
nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding = 1)  # stride = 1 by default.
```

This will keep the size of the tensor the same as the input in all 3 dimensions (height, width, and number of channels).

I will also add the formula to calculate size of output tensor in a convolution for reference.

```
output_size = ( (input_size - filter_size + 2*padding) / stride ) + 1
```